# Add new content after specific string in text file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I want to add the below snippet after the string `server {` in `nginx.conf` file.

```
location /nginx-status {
 stub_status on;
 allow all;
 }
```

The script below adds the snippet after `server {` wherever that string occurs. This is too much.

```
echo Nginx conf_file_directory
location=$(which nginx)
export location

echo "Nginx configuration file directory"
path=$($location -V 2>&1|grep -Po '(?<=--conf-path=).*?(?=/[^/]+(\s|$))')
export path
echo $path

dir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
echo $dir
export dir

echo "create nginx configuration content file"
cat << 'EOF' > $dir/content.txt
    location /nginx-status {
    stub_status on;
    allow all;
    }

EOF

echo "CONF_FILE file start"
sed -i  '/server {/r content.txt'  $path/nginx.conf

echo "Delete the nginx configuration content file"
file="$dir/content.txt"

if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    rm "$file"
   echo "deleted"
fi
```

The `nginx.conf` file contains more than one string `server {`. But I need to find only the first occurrence and add the new content below it. Only the first occurrence of `server {` is uncommented, all other occurrences are commented in `nginx.conf` file and they should be left alone.

How can I do this? How can I limit my code, so it adds new content *only* after the first occurrence of `server {`?

Comment: Note: the code you posted is not minimal (see [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659)). I think sole `sed -i '/server {/r content.txt' nginx.conf` plus the content of `content.txt` would be enough. (Some minimal content of `nginx.conf`, the actual result and the expected result would make the example complete; but one can understand the problem even without them.) An excessive script is better than no script, so it's not that bad. In the future try to post (more) minimal code. Achieving "minimal" without losing "complete" is not an easy skill, yet we should aim at this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work in GNU `sed`.

You can nest address ranges in `sed`. Start with your command which is:

```
sed -i  '/server {/r content.txt'  $path/nginx.conf
```

and turn it into:

```
sed -i '0,/server {/ {
//r content.txt
};' "$path"/nginx.conf
```

<sup>(I [fixed quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) here. In your script there are other places where quoting should be fixed.)</sup>

The trick is in the `0,/server {/` range. The range is from the first line to (and including) the line with the first occurrence of `server {`. It's similar to `1,/server {/`, but if `server {` occurs in the first line then `0,/server {/` will treat the first line as the end of the range, while `1,/server {/` would treat it as the beginning of the range (and thus it would end the range at the *second* occurrence of `server {`, if it exists). The variant with `0` is good for us, but I think it's not portable. GNU `sed` supports it for sure.

<sup>(If your `sed` does not support this `0` address, add a dummy (empty) line at the very beginning, use the `1,/server {/` range, ultimately remove the dummy line. Thanks to the dummy line, `server {` will never occur in the first line, so `1,/server {/` will work without the quirk.)</sup>

Only in this range the sed code inside `{ … };` is executed. This code is your original sed code (I just replaced `/server {/` with `//` which means "use the recently used regular expression", so it's effectively still `/server {/` but it's [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

After encountering the first occurrence of `/server {/`, `r content.txt` is executed and the range specified by `0,/server {/` ends. The range will match no further line because no further line is the first line. This guarantees that `r` is executed at most once.

Note:

- The content of `content.txt` will be added after the first *line* containing `server {`, not after the (sub)string `server {`. If the line is e.g. `server { foo` then it will stay like this and new content will appear below it, not between `{` and `foo`. Your original code works this way and I assumed this is what you want and the problem is only in limiting to the first occurrence.